# Product of Number input by user, program stops when user inputs 0

Tags: java, product

i want to make a program reads integers from the user one by one, multiply them and shows the product of the read integers. The loop for reading the integers
stops when the user presses 0. If the user enters a 0 as the first number, then user would not be able to provide any other numbers (Not adding the last 0 in the product). In this case, the program should display “No numbers entered!”

Heres my code right now

ProductNumbers.java

```
package L04b;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = -1;
    boolean isValid = true;
    int numbersEntered = 0;
    int product = -1;
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(
            "This program reads a list of integers from the user\r\n"
                    + "and shows the product of the read integers");

    while (num != 0) {
      System.out.print("Enter number = ");
      int curNum = scnr.nextInt();

      if (curNum == 0)
        break;
      numbersEntered++;
      product *= num;
    }
    if (numbersEntered == 0) {
      System.out.println("No numbers entered!");
    } else {
      System.out.println(product);
    }

    }
    }
```

I know this is completely wrong, i usually setup a template, try to figure out what needs to be changed, and go by that way, i also need to start thinking outside the box and learn the different functions, because i dont know how i would make it end if the first number entered is 0, and if the last number is 0, the program stops without multiplying that last 0 (so that the product doesnt end up being 0)... i need someone to guide me on how i could do this.

Heres a sample output of how i want it to work

```
This program reads a list of integers from the user
and shows the product of the read integers
Enter the number:
0
No numbers entered!
```

and

```
This program reads a list of integers from the user
and shows the product of the read integers
Enter the number:
2
Enter the number:
-5
Enter the number:
8
Enter the number:
0
The product of the numbers is: -80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested for loop, why? 
You only need the outer `while` loop that gets the user's input until the input is `0`.
Also this line:

```
product *= i;
```

multiplies `i`, the `for` loop's counter to `product` and not the user's input! 
Later, at this line:

```
if (isValid = true)
```

you should replace `=` with `==`, if you want to make a comparison, although this is simpler:

```
if (isValid)
```

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
int num = -1;
int product = 1;
int counter = 0;
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(
        "This program reads a list of integers from the user\r\n"
                + "and shows the product of the read integers");
while (num != 0) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num = scnr.nextInt();
    scnr.nextLine();
    if (num != 0) {
        counter++;
        product *= num;
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}

if (counter == 0)
    System.out.println("No numbers entered");
else
    System.out.println("Entered " + counter + " numbers with product: " + product);
```

Comment: Okay i see how this works, but how does this code not multiply the last "0" entered, im still confused as to how that is done

Comment: This line: `if (num != 0) {...}` does not allow the multiplication if the num is 0.

Comment: Ahhhh i see, this is exactly what i meant by i need to think outside the box aha, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to utilize the `break;` keyword to escape from a loop, and then you can process the final result after the loop.

Something like this:

```
int numbersEntered = 0;

while (num != 0) {
  int curNum = // read input
  if (curNum == 0)
    break;
  numbersEntered++;
  // do existing processing to compute the running total
}
if (numbersEntered == 0)
  // print "No numbers entered!
else
  // print the result
```

I think the key is to not try and do everything inside of the while loop. Think of it naturally "while the user is entering more numbers, ask for more numbers, then print the final result"